# What is the difference between AVAudioPlayer and MPMusicPlayerController?

Tags: iphone

It looks like both of them can play audio file.
What is the difference between AVAudioPlayer and MPMusicPlayerController?

Welcome any comment

Thanks
interdev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the class reference

MPMusicPlayerController:  http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

> You use an MPMusicPlayerController object, or music player, to play media items from the iPod library.

AVAudioPlayer: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

> An instance of the AVAudioPlayer class, called an audio player, provides playback of audio data from a file or memory.
>
> Apple recommends that you use this class for audio playback unless you are playing audio captured from a network stream or require very low I/O latency.